# Copying contents of file into array of linked list and sort it

Tags: java, arrays, oop, sorting, linked-list

I have a comma separated file that contains
Employee name,company,years.

An employee may be affiliated to multiple companies.

For eg,

> John,Google,2
>   John,Microsoft,1
>   James,Tesla,1
>   James,Apple,5

I have retrieved the information using the java scanner

```
scanner.useDelimiter(",|\\n");
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String line = scanner.next()
```

I am new to Java and I am trying to insert the above in a sorted order (using experience as sorting criteria) using an array of linked lists or array of array. So

employee -> Company1 -> Company2.... (ordered by employee experience)

So in the above example, it would be:

> John->Microsoft->google
>   James->Tesla->Apple

Can someone point me to the right direction?

NOTE: If the experience is same, it doesnt matter which company comes first.

Comment: There is a contradiction in the example you provided, because for `John` you sorted in ascending order while in `James` you did the opposite !?

Comment: edited my question iTech. I am kinda new to java ..i dont understand comparable

Comment: Do you care about the order of the actual people, as opposed to the companies that that person has worked at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this class for Person

public class Person {

```
@Getter @Setter
private String name;

@Getter @Setter
private TreeMap<String, String> companyExperience;

public Person(){
    companyExperience = new TreeMap<String, String>();
}
```

}

Using the experience as key in a TreeMap will automatically sort the companies for a Person in ascending order.

Your main class shoud look like this

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        HashMap<String, Person> persons = new HashMap<String, Person>();

        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Public Administrator\\test.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String line = null;

        try {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] fields = line.split(",");
                String personName = fields[0];
                Person existingPerson = persons.get(personName);
                if (existingPerson==null){
                    Person newPerson = new Person();
                    newPerson.setName(personName);
                    newPerson.getCompanyExperience().put(Integer.parseInt(fields[2])+fields[1], fields[1]);
                    persons.put(personName, newPerson);
                } else{
                    existingPerson.getCompanyExperience().put(Integer.parseInt(fields[2])+fields[1], fields[1]);
                }
             }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    

        //output
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Person>> entries = persons.entrySet().iterator();
        while (entries.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, Person> entry = entries.next();
            Person _person = entry.getValue();
            System.out.print(_person.getName());

            Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> companyExperiences = _person.getCompanyExperience().entrySet().iterator();
            while (companyExperiences.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String, String> companyExperience = companyExperiences.next();

                System.out.print(" > "+companyExperience.getValue());
            }
            System.out.println();

        }
    }
}
```

I've tested it and looks pretty, pretty good to me.

By the way, the @Getter and @Setter annotations are from the Lombok project. You can either use it or create your own getters/setters.

Comment: @Micheal unless I'm missing something, this solution will not handle the case of the same person having two equal length jobs, eg: James,Google,1 James,Apple,1  Give it a try.

Comment: @sharakan You are right. I've fixed it by using the experience+company (now, a String) as key of the TreeMap. Now it works in all cases.  Good point.

Comment: Now you have a similar problem, when you've worked at the same company twice for the same amount of time.  You really don't want a `Set` for this, as items should not be considered unique.

Answer (score 0):

read your file with `readLine()` and use split to get each field of your data, e.g.:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("FileName"));
String line = null;
ArrayList<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] fields = line.split(",");
    list.add(new Person(fields[0], fields[1], Integer.parseInt(fields[2])));
 }
```

You can then save your data in `ArrayList` that takes a custom class e.g. `Person` that stores the person's information and implements `Comparable` where you do the sorting logic.

If you need to group your data by the person name, you might consider having a `Hashtable` where the key is the person name and the value is `ArrayList` of experience.

You can define a class for your data, e.g.

```
class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    private String name;
    private String company;
    private int experience;

    public Person(String name, String company, int experience) {

        this.name = name;
        this.company = company;
        this.experience = experience;
    }

    public int getExperience() {
        return experience;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person person) {
        return new Integer(experience).compareTo(person.getExperience());
    }
}
```

The to sort your list just call `Collections.sort(list);`; however this list will contain all the data so modify the code to group the data by the employee name and have a list per each employee

Comment: -1 This doesn't give the results that OP wants.  Since you've got a Person object per line in the file, you'll have two objects per person name and thus the sort can split up the same person.  eg: your sorted list will have something like John:Microsoft:1, James:Tesla:1, John:Google:2, James:Apple:5

Comment: Correct, I missed those, just read the code!  My mistake.  You were leaving the final step of getting to his Emp->Comp1->Comp2 structure as an exercise for the reader?

Comment: `Can someone point me to the right direction?` this was the question and the solution from what I suggested is clear. In fact your answer to the question has a serious flaw, but I do not have time to comment on it

Answer (score 0):

For your purposes, it sounds like you really want an object to represent a Person, who has some amount of Experience.  Since your input source has the data denormalized, easiest way to do that is to populate a `Map<String,Person>` as you parse your file:

```
scanner.useDelimiter(",|\\n");
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String line = scanner.next();
    String[] fields = line.split(",");

    String name = fields[0];
    Person person = map.get(name);
    if (person == null) {
        person = new Person(name);
        map.put(name, person);
    }
    person.addJob(fields[1], Integer.parseInt(fields[2]));
}

List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>(map.values());
```

After this process, you'll end up with a List of People, in no particular order.  For each Person, since you want to keep their job's in order sorted by experience, you'd need to implement `Person.addJob` in such a way as to keep it ordered.  A [SortedSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) is a really nice way to do this, but you can't insert duplicates, and since you want to sort by experience, and a person could've been at two jobs the same amount of time you need to use an alternate approach.  There's several ways to do this, but without making assumptions about your data I'd suggest keeping a sorted `List` of `Job` objects:

```
class Person {
    private final List<Job> jobs = new LinkedList<Job>();

    // Constructor, etc... 

    public void addJob(String companyName, int yearsOfExperience) {
        Job newJob = new Job(companyName, yearsOfExperience);
        int insertionIndex = Collections.binarySearch(jobs, newJob);
        if (insertionIndex < 0) {
            insertionIndex = (-(insertionIndex) - 1);
        }
        jobs.add(insertionIndex, newJob);
    }
}
```

and finally, a `Job` should implement `Comparable<Job>`, so that you can look it up:

```
class Job implements Comparable<Job> {
    private final String companyName;
    private final int yearsOfExperience;

    // Constructor, etc... 

    public int compareTo(Job otherJob) {
        return Integer.compare(yearsOfExperience,otherJob.yearsOfExperience);
    }
}
```

That bit of trickery in `Person.addJob` will keep the `List` always sorted by the ['natural order'](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) of Job.  (see [Collections.binarySearch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T%29)).

Comment: @ITech You mentioned that this solution has a 'serious flaw'.  Hopefully at some point you have time to point it out to me.